# Combine IMAP LIST and STATUS commands

Tags: c#, imap

Is there a way to combine the IMAP commands to get a folderlist and the one to get the mail count of a folder.

```
$ LIST "" *
$ STATUS INBOX (messages)
```

These two are working, but a little bit slow.
I'm creating a program that needs these two infos from an IMAP server (e.g. Gmail) and it would be great to achieve this task with just one server request, because this costs valuable time.

I'm using c# with a self written class based on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29594/How-to-Access-Emails-Using-the-IMAP-Protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The protocol allows you to pipeline the commands, so you can issue the second while waiting for the result from the first.

Answer (score 1):

seit rfc 5819 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5819) geht das, sofern der serve es unterstuetzt:

$ LIST "" * RETURN (STATUS (MESSAGES))

__

According to RFC 5819 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5819), it is possible, as long as the server supports the following command:

```
$ LIST "" * RETURN (STATUS (MESSAGES))
```